# Midpoint of many places in a Map

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I wanna display many places in my map using the longitude, latitude and the Zoom... just like this site http://www.geomidpoint.com/

the code of my map :

```
 <map  center="{{mylatitude}},{{mylongitude}}" zoom="10" style="margin-top:-18px; margin-bottom: 50px; border: black solid 0px; position: relative; height:350px;width:100%;">

    <div  ng-repeat="itemToAdd in itemsToAdd">
         <marker  position="{{itemsToAdd[itemsToAdd.indexOf(itemToAdd)].lat}}, {{itemsToAdd[itemsToAdd.indexOf(itemToAdd)].long}}"></marker>

       <shape id="circle" name="circle" centered="true" 
  center="{{itemsToAdd[itemsToAdd.indexOf(itemToAdd)].lat}},{{itemsToAdd[itemsToAdd.indexOf(itemToAdd)].long}}"
  stroke-color='#FF0000' stroke-opacity="0.8" stroke-weight="2" 
  radius="{{itemsToAdd[itemsToAdd.indexOf(itemToAdd)].rayon}}" editable="true" ></shape>

    </div>
</map>
```

the Angular Js table itemsToAdd :

```
    $scope.mylatitude =48.8534100;
$scope.mylongitude =2.3488000;
$scope.zoom =10;
```

The default city is Paris( lat: '48.8534100',long: '2.3488000' )

Comment: are you facing any problem?

Comment: What's the question, what's the problem? If you looking for ready solutions that's not the place